# Dividing two select statements with 2 columns from 2 tables, MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wanting to get the percentage of females in each department.

**table: dept_emp**

```
| emp_no (Employee Number) | dept_no (department #)| 
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
|                        5 | 0                     |             
|                      500 | 1                     |             
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
```

**table: employees**

```
| emp_no (Employee Number) | gender                | 
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
|                        5 | M                     |            
|                      500 | F                     |             
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Here is what I have:

(this will get me the number of females in each department)

```
SELECT dept_no, count(*) FROM employees
INNER JOIN dept_emp
ON employees.emp_no=dept_emp.emp_no
WHERE (gender = 'F')
GROUP BY dept_no
```

(this will get me the total number of people in each department)

```
SELECT dept_no, count(*) FROM employees
INNER JOIN dept_emp
ON employees.emp_no=dept_emp.emp_no
GROUP BY dept_no
```

How do I divide these two then multiple it by 100? All while still showing which number aligns to the particular department. I've tried a few things, but I keep getting errors: "Operand should contain 1 column(s)". I feel like there's a way to set it up, I'm just not aware of how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using conditional count:

```
SELECT dept_no
     , ( coalesce(sum(gender = 'F'), 0) / count(*) ) * 100
FROM employees
JOIN dept_emp ON employees.emp_no=dept_emp.emp_no
GROUP BY dept_no
```